# Is there really any performance benefit in using pagination in web pages?

Tags: java, oracle, pagination

I'm programming a website in Java using struts as framework, and I tried to use pagination to break a query who could take too long to return, using a query similar to this:

```
select col
from   ( select col,rownum AS rn from table )
where  rn >= 1
and    rn <=10
```

That is from what I've seen the stardard way for doing pagination, but I don't see any performance improvement over just select the entire table and paginate in Java only, as for Oracle to calculate the `rownum`, it has to execute my query once.

Ideally I want to only search for a subset of this table results, instead of searching the whole table and then discarding part of the results.
Is there a way for doing that? Because if not, I can't see why lazy pagination would be better then just load the whole list and then separate in Java.

Comment: Whats the number of rows you are talking about? 100? 1000? 1000000?

Comment: What sizes of tables are you dealing with?   Are these tables being constantly updated?

Comment: try it on a database with 10.000.000 entries. I'm pretty sure you'll see some advantage then

Comment: If it's for searching a subset, try to add 'WHERE' to your SQL. As for pagination, I see that you don't have much data. Try it with a table of 10 millions of records. You will see that pagination is relevant.

Comment: well, I didn't tried much else, because  that's the only way to paginate results coming from the database I've seen, I don't know how else get these results. Right now I tried in an more or less empty table, and the results are ok, but seeing as it does a subquery without filters, I'm wondering if thats not the same as just do the subquery and break it in Java. There is another screen we tried this approach, where the sql is probably bad written, and gives socket error everytime due to huge amount of rows, but even paginating to bring 20 rows only, the result is no different.

Comment: my question here is, using this method for pagination I have to put my main query as a subquery and then filter this subquery. Is this not the same as just run the query without pagination and later on break the results? Is using pagination any faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, but you won't see it until you have enough data to simulate a fully grown database.

As others mentioned in the comments, generate a few million rows into your table, and *then* start using pagination and watch the plan of your query. Now you have something that has the smell of real-life, that you can compare to caching the table in memory.

Comment: Ah, I see, pagination benefits from  the query cache, so the first query may be a bit slow, but later on it will be faster.thanks

Comment: just to  rephrase my last comment, it is not that it runs on cache, I just tried with one of the biggest tables in the database and can see that even if the subquery has no filters, the pagination bring the results very fast

Comment: Also, if you cache the table in memory, inside your application, you'll have to update it whenever the table changes in the db :-)